# Two differenet entities (a library and a command) with the same name

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy

I`m trying to use a library and a command with the same name (from another library). How would this be possible?
These are the the relevant bits in my code:

```
import copy
```

and

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
```

The error I get is: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'

I guess this is because of the same name.
I`ve also tried

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

and got the same error.
Any idea how to address this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an *alias* for the later:

```
import copy
from xlutils.copy import copy as xlcopy
```

`copy` from `xlutils` will now be masked as `xlcopy`, and calling `copy.deepcopy` will now refer to the builtin `copy` module.